# node.js module require() twice -- (relative path)

Tags: node.js, express, module, require

Why the `QrChannelService` module required twice(mongoose throw a `overwriteMethod Error`), why it didn't be cached ?

> `QrChannelService` path:
>   mit/src/modules/qrchannel/services/QrChannelService.js

require

> path1:
>   mit/src/controllers/api/qr.js
>   var QrCodeService = require('../../modules/qrChannel/services/QrChannelService');

> path2:
>   mit/src/modules/qrchannel/common/QrHandlerDispather.js
>   var QrChannelService = require('../services/QrChannelService');

Comment: Is it the problem of the express.Router(), which will be cleaned out of the modules in the cache?  the router maintain a own group of modules?

Comment: If you try to load a module from two different paths, the module loader will not consider those the same module and will load each one separately.